# Image not displaying on php page

Tags: php, image

I have simple code on a php file in my cpanel which is connected to my website. The image is not displaying and is instead showing a little error box in place of the image. I've gotten the same error using html code and with using php echo

I've tried changing the file name to 'index.php' and that solves the issue.

I've tried changing the file name to have a .html instead and that solves the issue.

```
<img src='image.png'>
```

The image should display on a non-index php page with basic html code.

Comment: Is it possible to share links to broken and working pages?

Comment: On test.php, the image tag is just `<img src=".jpg" style="width:200px">` — it's missing an actual full file name. So if you're using a variable to output the file name, the variable may be empty.

Comment: In these cases the best thing is often to take it one step at a time. Can you get it to work without PHP? If so, can you get the filename to output from PHP correctly? and so on.

In this case you also have the PHP or HTML files in two different places, so they would need to point to the image in different ways. Look up relative and absolute ways of pointing to images for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your path on browser that image is coming or not.If it coming then it will be implemented on your dynamic code.

Share your error message also.

Comment: it's showing website/page/image, when maybe it should be showing website/image instead.